# How to convert from geometry_msgs PoseWithCovariance to nav_msgs Odometry?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, nav-msgs, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using package hector_slam to do mapping using Hokuyo laser on a ugv and I would like also to use package robot pose_ekf to get better position estimate from the wheels and laser.

I tried remapping poseupdate to vo but it throws an error that they are not of the same type, poseupdate holds the xyz and covariance.

any clue how to convert the geometry msgs PoseWithCovariance to nav msgs Odometry??
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199554/how-to-convert-from-geometry_msgs-posewithcovariance-to-nav_msgs-odometry?/) by [Ahmed Shehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/20092/ahmed-shehata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-15**:
This is probably not a good idea; I think the vo input on robot_pose_ekf uses the velocity estimate portion of the odometry message, and you're trying to provide the absolution position portion of the odometry message. You may want to investigate other kalman filter packages.

**Comment by [Ahmed Shehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/20092/ahmed-shehata/) on 2014-12-16**:
But it was already done for gps sensor, where they used a conversion package (gps_common) to convert from navsat to odometry. what other packages do you propose using? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look into the [ETHZASL_MSF](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_msf) package...

---

Originally posted by [Marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18988/marc/) with karma: 46 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0